# How to proporly configure wine

Tags: windows, wine, android, root

I have a program I need to use and currently do not have enough disk space for dual booting or a vm, so I was wondering if someone could port this program to Linux or help me configure wine to do so. This is the download link: [www.srsroot.com](http://www.srsroot.com/)

I am running Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: I just recently switched to linux, and don't know a whole lot yet, but im learning the basics of the shell, but have no experiance when it comes to coding.

Comment: Probably there is already a way to root your android phone from Linux. Why don't you post what phone you have and we try to work from there?

Comment: its an LG lucid 4g with ics 4.0.4 on verizon wireless.

Answer (score 0):

I see that software is for rooting an android device.  To do so you don't need that application, or wine at all.  Android, being linux, can be rooted and modified in many ways from a linux machine (including one running Ubuntu).  Of course, it might differ from phone to phone, but there are many guides out [there](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958438), and from many [sources](http://www.rojtberg.net/668/how-to-root-android-using-ubuntu/).

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. It helps alot, but my phone is an lg lucid 4g.

Comment: I found some [rooting instructions for your phone](http://androidforums.com/lucid-all-things-root/533930-root-one-click-root-lg-lucid-4-18-12-a.html) specifically, but I cannot verify whether it works or not.  Your best bet is to use some backup software to make a complete backup of your phone before you try those instructions.  Good luck.